# With Swift how do I remove all single character words from a string?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

For example, I have the following string:

```
e it z should a make q sense
```

and I want it to be:

```
it should make sense
```

Is there a single way to do this without having to create or loop through some character set?

Comment: It looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to achieve your goals.

```
let stringWithSingleChars = "e it z should a make q sense"
stringWithSingleChars.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\b\w\b"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

The pattern matches a word boundary, then a single word character, then a whitespace, resulting in all single-characters followed by a space being matched.

Comment: This would fail to remove a single character from the end of the string. The correct answer is `#"\b\w\b"#`

Comment: @LeoDabus good spot, thanks, updated my answer